# Android Browser PhoneGap no Caret (cursor) inside form

Tags: android, cordova

I'm at my wits end at this point... I can't get the text caret to appear when inside the input areas of the form.  This is a phonegap based app that is pretty simple to say the least.  onfocus through css I can put a yellow highlight around the text box though.. so obviously I'm getting focus.

this is what the form looks like:

```
<form method = "post" autocomplete="off" action="portal.html" style = "top:20%; width:250px; position:absolute; left:480px; right:auto; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;">

        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text"   name="username" maxlength="40" style = "font-size: 20px;"/> 
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"  maxlength="40" style = "font-size: 20px;"/>     
        <input type="submit" class="submit" style = "left:20px; position:relative; cursor:auto;"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What device are you using?

Unfortunately, each device implements WebView (the component most browsers and HTML-based Frameworks like PhoneGap use) differently, and some widgets like input widgets won't show a carat or a border, or will clobber their border (HTC is the worst offender).

Also, do you have any CSS style rules attached to your input elements? If so, remove them since they may also be hiding the carat.